# ImageMagick Invalid Image Index

Tags: screenshot, archlinux, imagemagick-convert

A week ago I followed [this](https://thurlow.io/linux/2017/11/10/replicating-macos-screenshot-utility-on-linux.html) tutorial, and it successfully worked (even with some changes I did), but today it just won't work.

The edited code is this:

```
SCREENSHOTFOLDER="/home/pk/screenshots"

FILE="${1}"
FILENAME="${FILE##*/}"
FILEBASE="${FILENAME%.*}"

# drop shadow: 60% opacity, 10 sigma, +0x +10y
convert "${FILE}" \( +clone -background black -shadow 70x15+5+10 \) +swap -background white -layers merge +repage "$SCREENSHOTFOLDER/${FILEBASE}.png"

notify-send -u critical -t 1 "${FILEBASE}.png saved."

xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i "$SCREENSHOTFOLDER/${FILEBASE}.png"
```

that code is run by this script:

```
 escrotum -s -e '/home/pk/ss/dropshadow-c.sh $f'
```

then, I tried to debug it but when I run  `escrotum  -s -e '/home/pk/ss/dropshadow-c.sh $f'` I get this:

```
convert: invalid image index `2021-04-18-201820_839x396_escrotum.png' @ error/list.c/CloneImages/282.
convert: no such image `+clone' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1027.
xclip: /home/pk/screenshots/2021-04-18-201820_839x396_escrotum.png: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I suspect you file path is incorrect or the file is not where you think it is.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried writing a fixed path, and still failing.

Comment: What version of Imagemagick?  I tried creating a shadow (uses +clone) and that command worked fine for me on IM 7.0.11.8 Q16 Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that ImageMagick has a bug in the version I used, I downgrade it and it works.